# Is there an Android Wear sms intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, wear-os

I've been trying to make a social media app that lets you send texts to your contacts from the watch. Is there an intent that does that for Android Wear?

I tried using the one from developer guides, but I get the error: "No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=vnd.android-dir/mms-sms (has extras)".

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hey, I am at {location}. Want to meet up?");
            intent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Wear devices don't have any Telephony features. You have to put your data to the phone (using the [DataLayer](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html)) and send the intent from it.

Comment: that page doesn't mention SMS, and, as usual, is extremely generic, with no code example given. So - for those of us not intending to amass a PhD-level of knowledge on Android or Wear OS, but just need the way to send a simple SMS. . would be great if someone could provide a working snippet. .

Answer (score 0):

For devices with cellular capabilities you can open the message composer using the following code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber);
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```